# How to fix 'Program type already present' in gradle

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, google-auth-library

I'm trying to add "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1" to my project, in dependencies node, and i'm getting an error when i'm running the project, the error is: **Error: Program type already present: com.google.android.gms.internal.auth.zzas**

I googled it, and i tried a lot of stackoverflow answers, but no one of them help, indeed no one of them really talking about my specific problem, in the end, i can't continue work on my project

Here's App Gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
     implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1' // Make the error!
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    .... }
```

Top Level Gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com/' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I expect to compile my project and use "play-services-auth" library, but my project can not compile, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After many attempts, I was just need to update the Gradle, and then everything is start to work.
Before.. I could not update the Gradle because an old version of OneSingal, thanks anyway..